# Fluent Iterable to array from a list that contain generic classes

Tags: java, generics, guava, toarray

I have the following class structure:

```
abstract class Role;
class Employee extends Role;
class Student extends Role;
class Employer extends Role;
```

Also I have an enum in which I store the acceptable roles.

```
public enum RoleEnum
{
      EMPLOYEE ("Employee", Employee.class),
      STUDENT ("Student", Student.class), 
      EMPLOYER ("Employer", Employer.class);

      final private String name;

      final private Class<? extends Role> pRoleClass;

      private RoleEnum(final String name, final Class<? extends Role> pRoleClass)
      {
            this.name = name;
            this.pRoleClass = pRoleClass;
      }
}
```

What I want is to get an array of elements of type `Class<? extends Role>` from a list of RoleEnums. I am using FluentIterable from Guava libraries and what I am trying to do is something like `FluentIterable.from(list).transform(function).toArray(Class<? extends PartyRole>)`. However what I managed to do is a workaround and kinda of a hack. It looks something like this:

```
(Class<R>[]) FluentIterable.from(roles)
                        .transform(new Function<RoleEnum, Class<R>>()
                        {
                            @Override public Class<R> apply(final RoleEnum role)
                            {
                                return (Class<R>) role.getRoleClass();
                            }
                        })
                        .toList().toArray(new Class[0]));
```

where

```
class RoleComboWidget<R extends Role>
```

is the class from where I call the method and

```
ImmutableList<RoleEnum> roles;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I see a question in here.  Additionally, for what it's worth, essentially _any_ interaction between generics and arrays will require hackery like this.  Generics and arrays really don't mix very well.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do something like `return Collections.stream(RoleEnum.values()).map(enumVal -> enumVal.pRoleClass).toArray(Class<? extends Role>::new);` in Java 8 instead?

Comment: We are still using Java 7 so hopefully when we migrate to Java 8 things will look a lot nicer with lambdas and all of the powerful tools from Java 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is the effect of combining arrays with generics. Arrays in Java are fully typed at runtime: the *component type* is available at runtime and load/store operations are type checked and may throw exceptions.

This requires the *component type* to be a *reifiable type*, but parameterized types like `RoleComboWidget<W>` are not. Generics are implemented in Java via invisible casts added at compile time, but once the program is running the JVM actually doesn't know if that is a `List<String>` or a `List<Integer>`.

Back to your problem, if you are in control of the API, be careful when requiring arrays instead of Collection (or Stream): rarely the benefits (usually in performance) outperform the drawbacks (usually in source-code maintenance). Also, be warned (the compile already warns you) that the cast to `SomeParameterizedType<T>[]` is always unchecked: as per the things explained earlier, you could end up with objects of the *wrong* type that may screw up or even halt your program.